# Call to presentViewController modify presenting view's frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller A that is presented like a popup window ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lswDZ.jpg)). This is achieved by leveraging iOS 7 custom transition and applying inset to A's frame.

From A, I present another view controller B using a regular `presentViewController` method and default transition. B will be displayed in full-screen as expected from a standard view controller behaviour.

The problem is, if I dismiss B, view controller A will be displayed as a full screen instead of being a popup window ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmYOo.jpg)). It seems that A's frame was modified somewhere by the default view controller transition. I want to keep A to be displayed like popup window. Anyone knows how can I achieve this?

Cheers,
Andree

Comment: why don't you re-set the A's frame in viewWillAppear?

Comment: I suppose that could be done, but if there's another way in which A can be agnostic about its own frame, that would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another custom transition to present view controller B, so that view controller A's view is not removed, and so you are in charge of what happens to view controller A's view on dismissal of B.

(I believe that this problem will not arise in the first place if you target iOS 8, where B can be set as `.OverFullScreen` and the existing views will be left undisturbed.)

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the suggestion. I tried to use a custom transition to present B. On dismiss, A would be displayed like a popup, but something seems to mess around with the offset (screenshot below). Do you know what might be the cause and how to get around this? 

http://imgur.com/Ge8B9Ik

Comment: What might be the cause might be your code, or it might not. Consider showing it.

Comment: Thanks I manage to solve the problem with this approach. For the offset problem, I simply record the offset value somewhere and restore it on dismissal.